# Using AWS Pipeline for a nightly data load

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I have following process that is run nightly:

1. Grab XML from an FTP server
2. Transform the XML with a number of XSLT's to XML formatted for MySql
3. Load the new XML using the "LOAD XML" mysql command

I've been reading about AWS Data Pipelines and instead of me having this process run on an Ec2 instance it sounds like aws pipelines may be suited for this but I have a couple questions:

- With step 2, the xslt's have some custom functions that are run. Currently the transforms are done with a .NET console app but I could convert this to Node if there is a way to do this in a cloud lambda
- Can the pipeline run a LOAD XML command on a database? I assume I'd have to out the xml to an s3 bucket?

Is AWS pipelines a good idea for this task or and I heading in the wrong direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very much possible with AWS Data Pipeline. See the following examples among many others in the github repository https://github.com/awslabs/data-pipeline-samples

ShellCommandWithFTP

RedshiftToRDS

You can transform your xml to CSV and use CopyActivity
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-copyactivity.html